# transparent html elements bug?

Tags: html, css

[image]

```
<div class="center main">
        <p id="bold">Enter 2 or more names</p>
        <input>
        <button>  
        <p id="bold">Enter your activities</p>
        <input>
        <button>Add</button>
        <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

```
    *{
    background-image: url(https://cdn.abcotvs.com/dip/images/6213304_052620-cc-ss-outdoor-picnic-img.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.main{
    background:rgb(255, 255, 255, .7);
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    border: solid;
}

.center{
    text-align: center;
}

button{
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 5px 12px;
}
```

I'm not worried about the layout since this is a copy from the original file but the original file also had this problem. I already tried it on a different browser(chrome, firefox, edge) but it doesn't look like it's a browser problem.

**THE PROBLEM**

As you can see, the space the html elements occupies are transparent. It wasn't like that 2 weeks ago and I haven't touched this in 2 weeks. I'm so confused on how and why this did just randomly happen??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this has changed over the past few weeks but what you can do is just add a background colour to the affected elements as seen below (just change the colours to whatever colour you want:

```
button{
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 5px 12px;
    background: blue;
}

p {
  background: red;
}

input {
  background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule to css:

```
.main > * {
    background: border-box;
}
```

Do you need that?

```css
*{
    background-image: url('https://png.pngtree.com/thumb_back/fw800/background/20190221/ourmid/pngtree-shading-background-abstract-colorful-background-colorful-art-image_22644.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.main{
    background:rgb(255, 255, 255, .7);
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    border: solid;
}

.center{
    text-align: center;
}

button{
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 5px 12px;
}

.main > * {
    background: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="center main">
        <p id="bold">Enter 2 or more names</p>
        <input>
        <button></button> 
        <p id="bold">Enter your activities</p>
        <input>
        <button>Add</button>
        <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```